# Making own function

Tags: python

I am trying to create a basic function in Python. Below you can see my code:

```
# Create function
def return_value_fun(type_1,type_2):
    if type_1 < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return type_1-type_2

# Testing function
return_value_fun(100,100)
```

This function working well. Now I want to put an additional argument `tb` into the function you can see below:

```
# Create function
def return_value_fun(type_1,type_2,tb):
    if type_1 < 0:
        return tb = 0
    else:
        return tb = type_1-type_2

# Testing function
return_value_fun(100,100)
```

Additional arguments make this function to not work. So can anybody help me how to solve this?

Comment: `return_value_fun(100,100)` you need to provide `tb` in the second example, or set a default.

Comment: I _think_ you want the first function and want to call it like `tb = return_value_fun(100,100)`

Comment: Regardless of what you pass i, `return tb = type_1-type_2` will throw an error, becuase you can return a variable assignment in a function. What is you expected output? What is `tb` supposed to be? Did you mean `return tb == type_1-type_2` to return a boolean whether they are equal or not?

Comment: @Kraigolas In the second example function can not be created. Is not a problem to provide argument in the function.

Comment: @G.Anderson I expect to output exactly the same as the output from the first function.

Comment: Just trying to understand your question better: If you want the same output, then what is the `tb = ` meant to do in the return?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Answer is :

```
# Create function
def return_value_fun(type_1,type_2):
    if type_1 < 0:
       tb = 0
    else:
        tb=type_1-type_2
        return tb
```

Comment: I think you forgot to return `tb` in your `if` statement. see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear as to what you're trying to do, but if you want to store the returned value inside a variable, it can be done like this:

```
# Create function
def return_value_fun(type_1,type_2):
    if type_1 < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return type_1-type_2

# Testing function
tb = return_value_fun(100,100)
```